# PyQT5 Designer add checkbox i Python when I have separate file for code

Tags: python, checkbox, pyqt5

My problem is that I have a file with my UI called xxx.ui. Then as many have suggested I created another python file called test.py where I have put code to use my xxx.ui:

```
# imports
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import uic
import sys


class Ui(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Ui, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('xxx.ui', self)
        
        self.show()


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Ui()
app.exec_()
```

Up until this stage everything works ok. But now I would like to add a checkbox to my UI whe program starts without messing inside xxx.ui (so the checkbox will be created dynamicaly when the program runs).

How can I do that ???

Thank You in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding. You created that ui file with Designer, right? Then, just open it again, add your checkbox and save it.

Comment: I have created xxx.ui file and then test.py file where i am connecting to that ui file. But since I dont want to mess in xxx.ui file i decided to add that checkbox dynamicaly in test.py file leaving xxx.ui file untouched.

Comment: Problem I have is: How to add that checkbox and how to refer to it later (i know I have to use findchild or something like that)

Comment: I don't know who told you you've to use findChild, but as long as you're using a UI created with Designer you certainly don't, as all widgets are accessible through their object name (`self.pushButton`, `self.tableWidget`, `self.label_2`, etc.), which is visible on the widget tree panel. I strongly suggest you to read the [Designer documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtdesigner-manual.html), as your question about adding the checkbox clearly shows that you need to clarify a lot of things in order to use it.

Comment: Managed to figure it out :) Thanks for help.

Comment: Ok, sorry but from your question it wasn't very clear what you were asking and I thought you were going to manually edit the .ui file.

Answer (score 1):

After many fail attempts I have found how to do it:

To add Checkbox outside of xxx.ui file. I went to my test.py file and added code below this line:

```
uic.loadUi('xxx.ui', self)
```

The code looks like that (I am using horizontal layout widget created in designer called seasonLayout and my checkbox is inside that layout):

```
self.checkBox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
self.checkBox.setObjectName("checkBox_0")
self.checkBox.setText('Hello')
self.seasonLayout.addWidget(self.checkBox)
```

Then if You want to get to that object all You have to do is to use code below:

(here i change text of this newly created checkbox):

```
self.checkBoxs = self.findChild(QtWidgets.QCheckBox, 'checkBox_0')
self.checkBoxs.setText('test')
```

Hopefuly it will be helpful for other because I have really tried to find answer for that almost everywhere and everyone were just using widgets from designer - noone explain how to add them outside of it.

Comment: Note that as long as you don't use complex class structures with dynamically created objects that have no persistent references, object names are rarely used to find objects in PyQt. In your case, for example, as long as the first `self.checkBox` is not going to be overwritten, you should access it using the same `self.checkBox` again. If those widgets *are* dynamically created indeed, you should probably use python data structures instead (and obviously you should not set them as `self` attributes). Besides the use for Designer UIs, Qt object names make sense almost only for css selectors.